# Auto update unique id

Tags: php, mysql, database, auto-increment

I have a table with a column 'id' which has auto_increment on.

So for example when I add a new record it will assign it a number.

But what I need is a way I can change the order of the records so for example there are 48 records in the db and I want record 29 to have the id of 5 instead of 29. So is there a way for record 29 to replace 5 and for them to all move up one so 5 would now be record 6 etc?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by ***auto update***? What exactly are the rules for shifting these records? What about going forward?

Comment: Do you still want the auto-increment id or do you want to assign the id all the time?

Comment: I mean if when adding or changing a records unique 'id' to one which already exists it will automatically move the one it is replacing up one and the ones above it

Comment: @ stark Not sure what you mean, why wouldn't I keep the auto-increment?

Comment: Because you want to insert out-of-order values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to allocate the id yourself, do not use an auto increment column.

A separate question is to do with renumbering records in a database table and yes, this can be done with an ordered update query.

First of all you would clear the space for the new record 5 thus:

```
UPDATE table SET id=id+1 WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Then you would renumber record 29 thus

```
UPDATE table SET id=5 WHERE id = 29
```

Comment: Why couldn't I use this with auto_increment?

Comment: You CAN use this with auto_increment. I simply meant that if you need to worry about the id value that records have then auto_increment is not the way to go!